# Django retrieve session user id

Tags: django, django-sessions

I am using login middleware to create a user login form.

**What is the best method to retrieve user id from view, after user successfully login?**

Created a middleware.py:

```
class LoginMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path != self.require_login_path and request.user.is_anonymous():
            if request.POST:
                return login(request)
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('%s?next=%s' % (self.require_login_path, request.path))
```

Comment: Wait, what's wrong with the normal auth middleware again?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, the problem I face is to retrieve the user id after login from view or template.

Answer (score 5):

Once a user has logged in, their associated `User` object is available via `request.user` in your template, automatically. When you say "user id", I'm not sure if you mean username or the literal value of `id` in the database. The same method applies for both, though: `{{ request.user.username }}` or `{{ request.user.id }}`.

Additionally, as the commenter above noted, there's no reason to create a new authentication middleware unless you need to change something in how the login is processed. Otherwise, leave it alone and use the default. (Which seems to be what you should be doing based on your middleware).

UPDATE: Neglected to mention that in order to access `request.user` in your template, you must pass in `RequestContext`. Example `render_to_response` below:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

render_to_response('templates/mytemplate.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks chris for the answer. I will try it out.

Comment: He probably needs to pass the RequestContext to the template, right?

Comment: I need the user id in view to retrieve data from database.

Comment: @geekam: Right. I always forget that because when do you actually *not* pass RequestContext in? ;). Still, it's not required, per se, so it's something a newbie might miss. Good catch.